# EF Core Code First - Create Relational Model in Visual Studio?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, visual-studio-2017, localdb, relational-model

I created a database by using Entity Framework Core Code First. Now I can view all my tables in my SQL Server Objekt Explorer which kind of looks like this:

[image]

Now I would like to create a Relational Model in Visual Studio so I can see all my relationships between my tables. But I can't figure it out how to do it. Is there a way Visual Studio can create a Model with my existing tables or do I need a Relational Database Management System?

I want my Model to look like this:

[image]

Comment: I don't think you can. You used to be able to do it but, in newer versions of Visual Studio, it has been removed! There are some paid 3rd party extensions that enable this though.

Comment: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ErikEJ.EFCorePowerTools